# Keyboard not showing on TextField focused in ModalBottomSheet compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

I have the following issue in compose.

I have a `ModalBottomSheet` which has a `TextField`. The keyboard does not show up when I click inside the text field. On an emulator I can type in some input with my computer keyboard shows up. On a real device though I don't have that possibility with makes the `ModalBottomSheet` useless.

I read this [article](https://patrykkosieradzki.com/how-to-fix-keyboard-issues-introduced-in-the-latest-jetpack-compose-1-4-0/) about the same issue and there identifying the version compose-ui 1.4.0 as source of the problem. So I went to this [page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.4.2) where they state that the issue has been fixed with version.
After updating my gradle as follows the keyboard still does not show up.

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size- 
 class:1.1.0-rc01"
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.2'
```

Comment: This works correctly for me using compose-bom = "2023.04.01" and material3 = "1.1.0-rc01", which should be the same as what you're using. Is there anything else that you're doing differently that could impact it or is this happening only on specific devices? I tested on a Pixel 7 Pro with code from https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material3/material3/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/material3/samples/BottomSheetSamples.kt;l=70-138.

Comment: Hi @IanG.Clifton, I also tried out that code and it didn't wor for me. Do you mind sharing your complete compose depencies? I think I might be missing something

Answer (score 1):

In case someone comes across here with a similar issue, ensure you have the `isFocusable` set to `true` (see below):

```
    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
        dragHandle = null,
        containerColor = Color.Transparent,
        scrimColor = Color.Transparent,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .statusBarsPadding()
            .navigationBarsPadding(),
        sheetState = sheetState,
        shape = RectangleShape,
        properties = ModalBottomSheetProperties(
            securePolicy = SecureFlagPolicy.SecureOff,
            isFocusable = true, // IMPORTANT!!! This must be true so TextField can show keyboard
            shouldDismissOnBackPress = false
        )
    ) {
        CheckoutSheetScaffold(checkout = checkout, onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest)
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using BOM 2023.04.01 and Material3 1.1.0-rc01, testing on a Pixel 7 Pro. I'm using a version catalog libs.versions.toml that looks like this:

```
[versions]
com-android-application = "8.1.0-alpha11"
org-jetbrains-kotlin-android = "1.8.20"
core-ktx = "1.10.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
androidx-test-ext-junit = "1.1.5"
espresso-core = "3.5.1"
lifecycle-runtime-ktx = "2.6.1"
activity-compose = "1.7.1"
compose-bom = "2023.04.01"
material3 = "1.1.0-rc01"

[libraries]
core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "core-ktx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-test-ext-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "androidx-test-ext-junit" }
espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espresso-core" }
lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx" }
activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activity-compose" }
compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "compose-bom" }
ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3", version.ref = "material3" }

[plugins]
com-android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "com-android-application" }
org-jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "org-jetbrains-kotlin-android" }

[bundles]
```

The dependencies from the build.gradle.kts file:

```
dependencies {

    implementation(libs.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.ui)
    implementation(libs.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.ui.test.manifest)
}
```

And the Compose snippet that works:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ModalBottomSheetSample() {
    var openBottomSheet by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()

    Button(onClick = { openBottomSheet = !openBottomSheet }) {
        Text(text = "Show Bottom Sheet")
    }

    if (openBottomSheet) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = { openBottomSheet = false },
            sheetState = bottomSheetState,
        ) {
            var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            TextField(value = text, onValueChange = {text = it} )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried with version catalogs with no success. I cannot explain what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your reply. I will definitely give it more time later.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing was happening to me: I used a `ModalBottomSheet` and I had to use a `BottomSheetScaffold()` and, in the content of the `bottomSheet`, I had to put a modifier with `VerticalScroll` to the column that contained the text fields.